# Prove that $\mu(E)=0$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $E\subset \mathbb {R^n}$ a measurable set and $(f_k)_{k\geq1}:E\to\mathbb {R}$ measurable functions such that for all $x\in E$ exist $M_x>0, \vert f_k(x)\vert\leq M_x\forall k$. If for all $\alpha>0$ exist $k_0(\alpha), k\geq k_0\to \mu(\{x\in E: \vert f_k(x)\vert<\alpha\})\leq \alpha/k$, prove that $\mu(E)=0$.

My attempt: put $E=\cup E_l, E_l=\{x\in E: M_x\leq l\}$. I'll prove that $\mu(E_l)=0$ for all $l$:

Define $f_k^l$ the restrictions of $f_k$ to $E_l$, and I can write $E_l=\{\vert f_k^l\vert \leq \alpha\}\cup \{\vert f_k^l\vert > \alpha\}$ for all k and $\alpha$.

Put $\alpha=l$, the second set is empty and $\mu(E_l)=\mu( \{\vert f_k^l \vert \leq l\})$ for all k.

Now, $\mu(E_l)\leq l/k$ for $k>k(l)$ sufficiently greater and $\mu(E_l)=0$.

I'm right? Any other solution more intuitive? Thanks!

Comment: I believe there is a typo and the last sentence of the problem should have $|f_k(x)|>\alpha$.

Comment: @Math1000 hmm no, <